# Modify DACL to prevent everybody kill process without Debug Priveleges

Tags: c++, windows, security, winapi, dacl

I have some code which i have wrote. I need to modify **DACL** ( security descriptor) in **Windows 10** to *prevent kill process* without *Debug Privilege* of user. How can i do this one? I learned at the internet algorithm, looked for some functions for that, but process still closes without any problems. I tried debug it a lot of time, code works without errors, but unsuccessfully.

How should i solve this problem? For my example below,i Add ACE for Denied PROCESS_TERMINATE. Is it right way?

Also advice me how can i check that. I know that i will get MessageBox of Permission Denied, yep?

My code (p.s. updated):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR GetProcessSecurityDescriptor(HANDLE processHandle, DWORD &buffSizeNeeded);
void SecurityDescriptorModifier(HANDLE hProcess);

int main()
{
    DWORD pID;
    std::cin >> pID;

    HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, pID);
    SecurityDescriptorModifier(processHandle);

    HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, false, pID);

    return 0;
}



void SecurityDescriptorModifier(HANDLE hProcess)
{
    DWORD                 SIDLength = 0;
    PSID                 SID;
    PACL                 pACL;   
    PACL                 pNewAcl;
    BOOL                 bDaclExist;
    BOOL                 bDaclPresent;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSecurityDescriptor;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSecurityDescriptorNew;
    ACL_SIZE_INFORMATION aclSizeInfo;
    DWORD                 dwNewAclSize;
    ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE*  pACE;
    PVOID                pTempAce;
    DWORD buffSizeNeeded = -1;


    // "everyone" group
    //CreateWellKnownSid(WinWorldSid, NULL, NULL, &SIDLength);
    // Allocate enough memory for the largest possible SID.
    SIDLength = SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE;
    if (!(SID = LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, SIDLength)))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate memory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //SID = new byte[SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE];
    if (!CreateWellKnownSid(WinWorldSid, NULL, SID, &SIDLength))
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "CreateWellKnownSid Error %u",
            GetLastError());
        LocalFree(SID);
    }

    pSecurityDescriptor = GetProcessSecurityDescriptor(hProcess, buffSizeNeeded);

    BOOL executionResult = GetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pSecurityDescriptor, &bDaclPresent, &pACL, &bDaclExist);

    if(!executionResult)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "GetSecurityDescriptorDacl() failed, error %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }

    pSecurityDescriptorNew = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, buffSizeNeeded);

    if (pSecurityDescriptorNew == NULL)
        exit(1);
    else
        printf("Heap allocated for psdNew!\n");

    // Create a new security descriptor
    if (!InitializeSecurityDescriptor(pSecurityDescriptorNew, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "InitializeSecurityDescriptor() failed, error %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }

    // Obtain the DACL from the security descriptor
    if (!GetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pSecurityDescriptor, &bDaclPresent, &pACL, &bDaclExist))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "GetSecurityDescriptorDacl() failed, error %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }

    // Initialize
    ZeroMemory(&aclSizeInfo, sizeof(ACL_SIZE_INFORMATION));
    aclSizeInfo.AclBytesInUse = sizeof(ACL);


    // Call only if NULL DACL
    if (pACL != NULL)
    {
        // Determine the size of the ACL information
        if (!GetAclInformation(pACL, (LPVOID)& aclSizeInfo, sizeof(ACL_SIZE_INFORMATION), AclSizeInformation))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "GetAclInformation() failed, error %d\n", GetLastError());
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    // Compute the size of the new ACL
    dwNewAclSize = aclSizeInfo.AclBytesInUse + sizeof(ACCESS_DENIED_ACE) + GetLengthSid(SID) - sizeof(DWORD);

    // Allocate buffer for the new ACL
    pNewAcl = (PACL)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwNewAclSize);

    if (pNewAcl == NULL)
        exit(1);

    // Initialize the new ACL
    if (!InitializeAcl(pNewAcl, dwNewAclSize, ACL_REVISION))
    {

        fprintf(stderr, "InitializeAcl() failed, error %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }
        static const DWORD dwPoison = PROCESS_TERMINATE;

    BOOL bResult = AddAccessDeniedAce(pNewAcl, ACL_REVISION, dwPoison, SID);

    if (FALSE == bResult)
    {
        printf("AddAccessDenied Error %d\n", GetLastError());
    }


    // If DACL is present, copy it to a new DACL
    if (!bDaclPresent)
    {
        // Copy the ACEs to the new ACL.
        if (aclSizeInfo.AceCount)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < aclSizeInfo.AceCount; i++)
            {
                // Get an ACE.
                if (!GetAce(pACL, i, &pTempAce))
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "GetAce() failed, error %d\n", GetLastError());
                    exit(1);
                }
                else
                    fprintf(stderr, "GetAce working\n");


                // Add the ACE to the new ACL.
                if (!AddAce(pNewAcl, ACL_REVISION, MAXDWORD, pTempAce, ((PACE_HEADER)pTempAce)->AceSize))
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "AddAce() failed, error %d\n", GetLastError());
                    exit(1);
                }
                else
                    fprintf(stderr, "AddAce() is working!\n");
            }

        }

    }


    if (!SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pSecurityDescriptorNew, TRUE, pNewAcl, FALSE))
    {
        printf("SetSecurityDescriptorDacl() failed, error %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("SetSecurityDescriptorDacl() is working!\n");

    // Set the new security descriptor for the window station
    if (!SetKernelObjectSecurity(hProcess, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, pSecurityDescriptorNew))
    {
        printf("SetUserObjectSecurity() failed, error %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("SetUserObjectSecurity() is working!\n");
}


PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR GetProcessSecurityDescriptor(HANDLE processHandle, DWORD &buffSizeNeeded)
{
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = new byte[0];
    SECURITY_INFORMATION si = DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION;

    // To understand actual needed size for pSD
    // GetKernelObject, what diff?
    GetKernelObjectSecurity(processHandle, si, pSD, 0, &buffSizeNeeded);

    if (buffSizeNeeded <= 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, ":GetKernelObjectSecurity ERROR: %u\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }

    pSD = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, buffSizeNeeded);

    if (pSD == NULL)
        exit(1);
    else
        printf("Heap allocated for psdNew!\n");

    //Allocate Memory & get DACL
    if (!GetKernelObjectSecurity(processHandle, si, pSD, buffSizeNeeded, &buffSizeNeeded))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, ":GetKernelObjectSecurity(With Alloc) ERROR: %u\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }

    return pSD;
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to *achieve*?

Comment: Deny ACEs need to be added to the head of the ACL, otherwise a prior Allow ACE will match. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/order-of-aces-in-a-dacl

Comment: @JesperJuhl we have process, i need to write program which will get Security Descriptor of process and modify it so that no one can close the process without debug priveleges.

Comment: @JonathanPotter yep, maybe! I'll try it, thx a lot for advice!

Comment: You can simplify this code by using `GetSecurityInfo`, `SetEntriesinAclW`, and `SetSecurityInfo`. This will also do the right thing in terms of canonical ordering of entries.

Comment: you not need add any ace to acl, enumerate existing and remove from `Mask`  `PROCESS_TERMINATE` access if this is not LocalSystem or Administrators sid

Comment: @JonathanPotter so, i add denied ace to the head, when in code execute     OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, false, pID) i really get ERROR 5 (Access Denied). It's ok. But why when i close "calc.exe" ,in my case, by click cross it closes as usuall, without any messagebox about access denied?

Comment: because window handle wm_close message and exit itself

Comment: @RbMm But if there is a denied ACE on the head of ACL, then it will not check the lower ones in ACL, right?

Comment: but for what you need add denied ace ?

Comment: @RbMm **I need to modify DACL ( security descriptor) in Windows 10 to prevent kill process without Debug Privilege of user.** So, I googled it and there said it is necessary to denied PROCESS_TERMINATE to WorldSid(Everyone), what i do in my code

Comment: but i ask for what you need **add** denied ace ? you can for example set empty dacl to process. this denied access too. or remove `PROCESS_TERMINATE` access right from mask

Comment: @RbMm At first, when i started to write code, I thought it was easiest to add a denied ACE. Okey, which way is easier and more reliable in the end?

Comment: no , you select most worst and hard solution. you can simply set empty dacl to process for example. or if want selective disable access - remove PROCESS_TERMINATE access right from some sids in `ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE`

Comment: If you need to block `WM_CLOSE` messages to a process for which you don't have source control, you can run it elevated "as administrator". UIPI will block messages sent from a standard-user security context, e.g. sent by taskkill.exe from non-elevated command prompt. Or, more radically, I suppose you can run the process on another Desktop in WinSta0, to which you lock down access.